# $localStroage array doesn't match $scope array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, local-storage

I am pushing Objects to a `$localStorage` array for persistence. I also check this array to see if an object is present before adding / removing an Object (if present it should `splice` if not present then it will `push`).

When I refresh my page the data returned from `$localStorage` doesn't seem to be the same as it was pre-refresh as my check function doesn't work, despite it looking EXACTLY the same on inspection.

**Objects being pushed are structured like this:**

```
    {
    "createdAt": "2015-04-24T10:21:21.649Z",
    "difficulty": "Hard",
    "exerciseDescription": "Lie on your back on a bench and take hold",
    "exerciseID": "3101",
    "exerciseName": "Bench Press",
    "images": [8679, 8680, 8682],
    "tags": ["Barbell", "Horizontal Flexion", "Extension", "Strength", "Chest", "Triceps", "Shoulder", "Elbow, Wrist & Hand"],
    "updatedAt": "2015-09-09T20:14:59.681Z",
    "words": ["bench", "press", "chest"],
    "objectID": "ak6t7ukQdY",
    "_highlightResult": {
        "exerciseName": {
            "value": "Bench Press",
            "matchLevel": "none",
            "matchedWords": []
        }
    }
}
```

**Check if object if present (toggle add/remove)**

```
$scope.addExerciseToProgramme = function(exercise) {

    if (!$localStorage.Programme) {
        $localStorage.Programme = [];
    }

    var index = $localStorage.Programme.indexOf(exercise);

    if (index > -1) {
        $localStorage.Programme.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        $localStorage.Programme.push(exercise);
    }
}
```

**Function to watch/load $localStorage**

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $localStorage.Programme
}, function(programme) {
    $scope.programme = programme;
});
```

**ng-class to check if exercise is in programme**

```
  <i class="exercise-add-indicator ion-ios-checkmark-outline" ng-class="{'orange': programme.indexOf(exercise) > -1}"></i>
```

**Problem**

There are two problems with this:

1. Following refresh, the `ng-class` doesn't conditionally add the class depending on the content of my `$scope.programme`
2. The `addExerciseToProgramme` function doesn't respect the `indexOf` check and pushes the exercise object to the array regardless!

Comment: Can you produce jsFiddle of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.indexOf()` uses strict equality: *An expression comparing Objects is only true if the operands reference the same Object.*

You shouldn't use this when working with localStorage.

When saving an object to localStorage it's turned into a string. When retrieved it's turned into an object again.

This will however be a new object, even if it looks exactly the same.

For example, this will yield `false`:

```
var object1 = { id: 1 };
var object2 = { id: 1 };

console.log(object1 === object2);
```

To get it working you can implement a custom function that retrieves the index based on the value of a property of your choosing. Note that it should be **unique**.

For example:

```
$scope.getExerciseIndex = function(exercise) {

  var index = -1;

  if (!$scope.programme) return index;

  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.programme.length; i++) {

    if ($scope.programme[i].exerciseID !== exercise.exerciseID) continue;

    index = i;
    break;
  }

  return index;
};

$scope.exerciseExists = function(exercise) {

  var index = $scope.getExerciseIndex(exercise);
  return index > -1;
};

$scope.addExerciseToProgramme = function(exercise) {

  if (!$localStorage.Programme) {
    $localStorage.Programme = [];
  }

  var index = $scope.getExerciseIndex(exercise);

  if (index > -1) $localStorage.Programme.splice(index, 1);
  else $localStorage.Programme.push(exercise);
};
```

HTML:

```
... ng-class="{'orange': exerciseExists(exercise) }" ...
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/R6TEisvQ7gkDcwBgw0D1?p=preview

Comment: Incredible answer and effort with putting a plnkr together! Cannot thank you enough works perfectly!!